# Remove everything between two strings

Tags: php, preg-replace

Need to remove everything between .jpg and > on all instances like these below:

- .jpg|500|756|20121231-just-some-image-3.jpg)%>
- .jpg|500|729|)%>
- .jpg|500|700|)%>
- .jpg|500|756|test-43243.jpg)%>

So everything becomes .jpg>

Any suggestions using preg_replace?

Comment: You need to accept an answer at some stage, or give feedback on why the existing answers don't help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_replace('/\.jpg[^>]+>/', '.jpg>', $your_string);
```

Comment: That looks like it should work, though the * should probably be a + to avoid replacing .jpg> with .jpg> :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = '.jpg|500|756|20121231-just-some-image-3.jpg)%>';
preg_replace('/[^\.jpg][^>]+/', '', $str);
```

Comment: I don't think [^\.jpg] will do what you want it to do here... it's equivalent to [^pjg\.] to highlight the problem...

Comment: `$str = '.jpg|500|756|20121231-just-some-image-3.jpg)%>';
preg_replace('/(\.jpg)[^>]+/', '$1', $str);`